# Where can I get public transportation route information for USA?

Tags: python, openstreetmap, google-maps, r, transportation

I'm trying to find a list of public transit route information, mainly location of bus and train stops for the US.  I've looked around at some of the Google products and openstreetmap but can't find anything.  Any suggestions?  Where does Google get their info?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Google uses the GTFS  (General Transit Feed Specification) standards**

https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/

The **Full List** of all the live feeds

http://code.google.com/p/googletransitdatafeed/wiki/PublicFeeds

> This is a list of transit schedule data published by transit agencies
>   and operators in GTFS format for developers to use. They contain
>   scheduled times, stop locations, route information and optionally fare
>   information and detailed route shapes.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, they created a standard and now a number of transit agencies are making data available in that format: http://code.google.com/p/googletransitdatafeed/ and http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/06/public-transit-routing-and-layer-now.html.  As for a single source for the country, that might be a tough one.